# Python 3 Pandas How to Tally (count in ascending/decending order) Duplicates in a Dataframe as They Occur

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, counter

There are many great examples of how to count duplicates in Python3 Pandas, but am having a hard time figuring out 'tally' the duplicates as they occur.  For example: A dataframe column has 4 occurrences of a value, I don't want 4 as an answer, instead I'm looking for 1, 2, 3, 4 value in a new column.

```
MyCol     Tally  DecendingTally
'a'         1          4
'a'         2          3
'b'         1          2
'b'         2          1
'a'         3          2
'd'         1          1
'a'         4          1
```

I tried:

```
df['Tally'] = df['MyCol'].count()
```

...Which gives me the correct count repeating, but not a tally.  Any suggestions?  Any way to make it decend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and add `1`:

```
df['Tally'] = df.groupby('MyCol').cumcount().add(1)
df['DecendingTally'] = df.groupby('MyCol').cumcount(ascending=False).add(1)
print (df)
  MyCol  Tally  DecendingTally
0   'a'      1               4
1   'a'      2               3
2   'b'      1               2
3   'b'      2               1
4   'a'      3               2
5   'd'      1               1
6   'a'      4               1
```

Comment: cumcount() ! I used it years ago but forgot about it.  Good to see an ascending function on it.